# count multiple values in a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope everyone is doing well I have a question regarding whether we can count multiple values at once in excel as below:

what is in column

```
**Name**
a
a
a
b
b
c
a
```

what I want to count individuals at once as below:

```
**a**    **b**     **c**
4          2          1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Pivot table maybe?

Comment: I tried pivot but its a single column

Comment: And what is the problem with single column?

Comment: @basic as where to  put this column in pivot table to get desired output?

Comment: @MaxMiak if you want a pivot table just put the Name column in both columns and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Excel 365.

In **C1** enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A8))
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,C1)
```

and copy across.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Please note the excellent suggestions made by *JvdV* and *chris neilsen*.  These improvements will allow column **A** to be modified *(items added/removed)* without having to go back and mod the formulae.

In **C1** enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(ROW(A:A)>1)*(A:A<>""))))
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,C1#)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the references be `$A2:$A8`?

Comment: @VBasic2008  Great question! .................it turns out that in the new dynamic spillable formulas, the references do not propagate with the spill, so the **$** are not needed.

Comment: @VBasic2008  In the `COUNTIF()` formula I am not using spill, so I do need the **$** s

Comment: You can make the Count Spill with `CountIf(A2:A8, C1#)`

Comment: And you can make the solution fully dynamic wit (in C1) `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(ROW(A:A)>1)*(A:A<>""))))` and (in C2) `CountIf(A:A, C1#)`

Comment: Little fun alternative: `=CHOOSE({1,2},TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A8)),COUNTIF(A2:A8,TRANSPOSE(,UNIQUE(A2:A8))))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Great suggestions! If you Post an Answer, I, for one, would up-vote and recommend it be the Accepted Answer.

Comment: IMHO no need for another answer, free free to include it in yours